# Installation v8js in php

Tags: php, linux, v8

Try to install v8js extension by command:

```
sudo pecl install v8js-0.1.5
```

but at the end of installation I got:

```
checking for V8 files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the v8 distribution
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-v8js' failed
```

Also at the middle of installation I got question:

```
Please provide the installation prefix of libv8 [autodetect] :
```

What I have to answer?

Comment: This type of issue, in my opinion, is more suited for Superuser (http://superuser.com/) or ServerFault (http://serverfault.com/). Probably on Superuser might be the best place to post it. If you want, you can ask to migrate to over there.

Comment: Ok, whom I can ask for that?

Comment: I have flagged it by marking it to require attention from a moderator. Lets see what they have to say